# Deploying an non-Jar executable from a Maven build

Tags: maven, binaryfiles

I have a maven build that produces a binary executable.  This executable is not a jar.  It happens to be a linux executable file.  This is produced by a separate process that is executed by the custom execution of the exec-maven-plugin, attached to the install phase.  We then have a script invoked from another custom execution of the exec-maven-plugin, attached to the deploy phase, which "deploys" the executable to a filesystem location.

How can I deploy this executable as a real maven artifact in a nexus repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use maven-deploy-plugin. A similar scenario is documented here [1]

[1] [How can I deploy a zip file created with the maven-antrun-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428369/how-can-i-deploy-a-zip-file-created-with-the-maven-antrun-plugin)

hth

Comment: Do you happen to know how the deploy:deploy locates the file it's going to deploy?

Comment: I think by default it deploys, .jar and .zip files found under target folder - (i'm not 100% sure about the statement).