# How do I deploy an RPM in artifactory so artifact coordinates are preserved?

Tags: maven

I have an artifact called myArtifact-5.6.1-198867.x86_64.rpm. However when deploy it into artifactory using the **default maven-deploy-plugin**, I get

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompany.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
    <type>rpm</type>
</dependency>
```

I expect

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompany.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1-198867</version>
    <type>x86_64.rpm</type>
</dependency>
```

IOW a lot of the information in the original filename is NOT preserved? How can I modify my pom file so the info is preserved?

Comment: The part `x86_64` is from maven point of view a classifier which can be defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428369/how-can-i-deploy-a-zip-file-created-with-the-maven-antrun-plugin

This post answers my question.